# Connect ECONNREFUSED contenedor Node, conectándose a Django en Docker

Tags: nodejs, django, docker, docker-compose

Intento conectarme desde un contenedor Node a un contenedor Django en Docker-compose. Pero me da error:

```
    CONNECTED TO: 144.178.129.236:4757
    node_1          | { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
    node_1          |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]                      (net.js:1097:14)
    node_1          |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    node_1          |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    node_1          |   syscall: 'connect',
    node_1          |   address: '127.0.0.1',
    node_1          |   port: 8000 }
```

Se conecta desde un servidor net en Nodejs, con la librería XMLHttpRequest. Parece que lo intenta 3 veces y a la tercera this.readyState es igual a 4 pero this.status sigue estando a 0.

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/version/'
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
     ....
     }else{
        console.error(xhttp.statusText);
     }
   };
   xhttp.open('POST', url, true);
   xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(trace));
```

Mi local.yml es el siguiente en lo que a estos dos contenedores se refiere:

```
django: &django
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
image: hegeo_local_django
depends_on:
  - postgres
volumes:
  - .:/app
env_file:
  - ./.envs/.local/.django
  - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
ports:
  - "8000:8000"
command: /start

node:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: ./compose/production/nodejs/Dockerfile
image: hegeo_node
depends_on:
  - postgres
links:
  - postgres
ports:
  - "4757:4757"
networks:
  default:
    ipv4_address: 144.178.129.236
```

He comprobado que 144.178.129.236:4757 esté dentro de ALLOWED_HOSTS, CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS y CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST en las settings de Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fijate que el contenedor Node lo tienes configurado para conectarse contra **http://127.0.0.1:8000/version/**.

Esa 127.0.0.1 es el loopback interno del contenedor, NO es el loopback del host donde se ejecuta los contendores. 
Si cambias la url de conexión de la 127.0.0.1 a la IP del host donde se ejecutan los contenedores deberia funcionarte.

Pero seria mas correcto que siguieras la [documentación de docker](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) respecto al networking de contenedores.

---

> For example, suppose your app is in a directory called myapp, and your
>   docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
```

> When you run docker-compose up, the following happens:
>
> 1. A network called myapp_default is created.
> 2. A container is created using web’s configuration. It joins the network myapp_default under the name web.
> 3. A container is created using db’s configuration. It joins the network myapp_default under the name db.

---

Levantando los contenedores con docker-compose te creara una red interna por la cual los contenedores se podrán comunicar. (puedes ejecutar **docker network ls** para comprobar si la red existe).

Dentro de esa red los contenedores se podrán comunicar con el nombre que le has dado en el docker-compose. Prueba a hacer un ping a django desde el contenedor node.

Comment: Perfecto! Con el comando "docker network inspect mynetwork" he conseguido la ip a la que me debo conectar en el contenedor de Django, he puesto dicha IP en ALLOWED HOST en mi settings, y funcionando. Muchas gracias. Brillante tu respuesta.